# Ordered list including parent number. How to style decimals?

Tags: css

I've got ordered list which is including parent index.

I would like to make decimals bold, how can this be approach?

```css
ol.list {
    list-style: none;
    counter-reset: roman;
}
ol.list > li:before{
    counter-increment: roman;
    content: counter(roman, upper-roman)".";
}
ol.list > ol {
    list-style: none;
    counter-reset: inner;
}
ol.list > ol li:before{
    counter-increment: inner;
    content: counter(roman, upper-roman)". "counters(inner,'.') ".";
    padding-right:5px;
}
```

```html
<ol class="list">
  <li>Item</li>
  <ol>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
  </ol>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 2):

This one will work for you. It is done by **your own code only some CSS tweaks**.

**Regarding this method**

**CSS** has the `::first-letter` pseudo-element selector, which selects the first letter in the text but there's no equivalent to `::last-letter` selector or `::second-first-letter` selector in  **CSS** till now.

```css
ol.list {
    list-style: none;
    counter-reset: roman;
}
ol.list > li:before{
    counter-increment: roman;
    content: counter(roman, upper-roman)".";
}
ol.list > ol {
    list-style: none;
    counter-reset: inner;
}
ol.list > ol li{
position:relative;
}
ol.list > ol li:before,ol.list > ol li:after{
    content: counter(roman, upper-roman)".";
    left: -28px;
    font-weight:normal;
    position:absolute;
}
ol.list > ol li:after{
    counter-increment: inner;
    content:counters(inner,'.')".";
    left: -15px;
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

```html
<ol class="list">
  <li>Item</li>
  <ol>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
  </ol>
</ol>
```

Comment: Regarding your note: it seems possible to set `font-weight:bold` for the whole `:before` pseudo element and then override it with `font-weight:normal` for the `:first-letter` only, leaving the rest of the counter bold. Just tested it in Chrome/Win, it works.

Comment: @IlyaStreltsyn But what about the **`.`** after the `I`.?

Comment: It seems also to have the styling of `:first-letter` because [this selector is rather smart](https://www.sitepoint.com/12-little-known-css-facts-the-sequel/#6-the-first-letter-pseudo-element-is-smarter-than-you-think). But I haven't tested it in all browsers yet.

Comment: @IlyaStreltsyn please paste a fiddle or an answer, I have to check that, because I have tried that method but I was not successful.

Comment: Sorry, I just tested it with the OP's code — the `.` is treated as part of `:first-letter` in IE11, but doesn't in both Chrome and Firefox. Will investigate it later, probably it's a browser bug.

Comment: @IlyaStreltsyn It's k bro. always share your knowledge and opinions, we all are here to learn. :)

Answer (score 0):

```css
ol.list {
    list-style: none;
    counter-reset: roman;
}
ol.list > li:before{
    counter-increment: roman;
    content: counter(roman, upper-roman)".";
}
ol.list > ol {
    list-style: none;
    counter-reset: inner;
}
ol.list > ol li{
    padding-left:30px;
    position: relative; 
}
ol.list > ol li:before{
    counter-increment: inner;
    content: counter(roman, upper-roman)".";
    position:absolute;
    left:5px;
}
ol.list > ol li:after{
     content: counters(inner,'.')".";
     font-weight:bold;
    position:absolute;
    left:15px;
}
```

```html
<ol class="list">
  <li>Item</li>
  <ol>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
  </ol>
</ol>
```